# Why this positive lookahead regex 'string.*?(?= )' doesn't work in sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a long list of something like:

```
AllowedUsers aaaa01@11.22.33.44 aaaa03@11.22.55.77 bbbb11@99.99.99.99 ccc00@11.0.0.11 .....
```

all in single line. Basically it's bunch of username@ip

I wanted to do a find and replace just by using its username (e.g. aaa) and replace it with nothing.

I tested my regex ([RegExr](https://regexr.com/4thjl)) and it works as I expected. But when I try to do it on `sed`, it didn't work.

```bsh
$ sed 's/bbbb11.*?(?= )//' test
AllowedUsers aaaa01@11.22.33.44 aaaa03@11.22.55.77 bbbb11@99.99.99.99 ccc00@11.0.0.11 .....
```

I also tried using `bbbb11.*?(?=[[:space:]])`, it didn't work either.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Your expression appears to be a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).  The `sed` utility expects a POSIX basic regular expression, or a POSIX extended regular expression if you use its non-standard `-E` option. This question appears to be a duplicate of [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Positive (`?=`) and Negative lookahead (`?!`) assertions work well only in a tool that supports [PCRE extensions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). Neither GNU `sed` nor POSIX support these library extensions. You need `perl` which supports it out of the box

```
perl -pe 's/bbbb11.*?(?= )//'
```

Or you can very well achieve the same without the regex support. For such trivial substitutions you can do something as below which works in both POSIX and GNU `sed`

```
sed 's/\(bbbb11[^ ]*\)//'
```

Comment: Thanks for adding regex alternative for sed.